# What do you call a person who is against incest?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

What do you call a person who is against incest? I have tried asking Google numerous times, each time coming out empty handed. There seems to be lots of difficulty looking up that specific word. I'm doing a school research assignment on attraction and I wanted a more sufficient word to use instead of a sentence. (ex:" people who are against incest").Basically ,I wanted one word to shorten that. And if you are wondering, some people are actually okay with incest, so instead of putting an "all" on that tidbit I've decided to put a "some".

Comment: You may safely assume for rhetorical purposes that everyone is against incest. So terms such as "people," "society," "the citizenry," etc., will convey the meaning.

Comment: Something like "normal" would probably work too.

Comment: "Taboo-typical"

Comment: Why would you want a word for that? I can't even.

Comment: @Gabby I am not flagging this since I do not personally see the point in doing so, but I feel like I should mention that this is a [tag:single-word-request] and that category of question requires an exemplary sentence, which is rationalized as allowing us to pick the best word available if one exists and see that the requested word is needful. You should edit such a sentence in, and add the tag while you're at it, otherwise it is likely that the question will be closed.

Comment: I'm doing a school research assignment on attraction and I wanted a more sufficient word to use instead a sentence ex:" people who are against incest". Basically ,I wanted one word to shorten that sentence. And if you are wondering, some people are actually okay with incest, so instead of putting an "all" on that tidbit I've decided to put a "some". So excuse me if I needed an actual word that means that. @NVZ

Comment: Tonepoet beat me to it.  If there is a specific word, the context would be needed to understand what you mean by "against".

Comment: @Gabby Well, please add that information to the question body by clicking on the "edit" link under it.

Comment: @Tonepoet thank you for not flagging!, I did as you suggested I'm entirely new to how this works so again, thanks.

Comment: Suggestion taken. @NVZ

Comment: Because of the usual taboo against incest, it might be more likely to find a word or term for the marked situation (pro-incest), which is usually where words are needed, and then negate it.

Comment: Wait... all this time you were talking about incest? I misread it initially as 'insects' and have been responding in kind since.

Comment: Assumiong we're limiting this to cultures where incest is an aberration, it could depend on the reason the person is against it (social norms? medical considerations? religious reasons?).  Is the person sitting in a room thinking about incest and logically concluding that it is bad, or worked into a lather about it and protesting in the street?  Is the person against the practice only as a personal matter, or wants to ensure others don't engage in it?  The applicable term could be different depending on the context.  The answer to the question in the title could be "Bob".

Answer (score 1):

Take *pro* and *anti* as prefixes to imply approval and disapproval, respectively.

***Anti-incest*** -- [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/anti-incest)

> *adj.* Opposed to incest and [incesters](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/incester)

Answer (score 0):

*Incest critics* and *those tolerant of incest* or *those who tolerate incest*.

Comment: Incest is unlawful contact between kin too close to legally marry. So it is a legal thing and moreover one which varies dramatically by jurisdiction.  Cousin marriage for example is not incest save where prohibited by law.